# Is there a way to create a global variable that can be access within all activities

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to create a global variable that can be accessed by all activities and any changes made to it in one activity will be made to the variable for other activities.

What I'm trying to do is have a points system within my app, so the points are the same across the app and points can be added to the variable from any activities.

Comment: Add a public property|variable to your application subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the application class to your project, something like below:

```
 public partial class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public static int GlobalPoints { get; set; }
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
     : base(handle, transer)
    {

    }
    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
       // UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
       // RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Android.App.Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       // Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(activity, savedInstanceState);
       // CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        //ActivityContext = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        //   throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        //CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
       // ActivityContext = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Android.App.Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
        /// throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        //CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
       // ActivityContext = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Android.App.Activity activity)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can access this variable anywhere in your app something like:

```
MainApplication.GlobalPoints= 1000;
```